# Customizing mat-menu component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14

Is it possible to customize mat-menu in angular?

I have to set this arrow (in red circle) in left side of word (green circle)

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined cursor-pointer" [matMenuTriggerFor]="settings"> settings </span>
    <mat-menu #settings="matMenu" xPosition="before">
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="candidats">Candidats</button>
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="clients">Clients</button>
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="permanents">Permanents</button>
        <mat-menu #candidats xPosition="before">
            <button mat-menu-item>Candidats</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>Clients</button>
        </mat-menu>
        <mat-menu #clients xPosition="before">
            <button mat-menu-item>Candidats</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>Clients</button>
        </mat-menu>
        <mat-menu #permanents xPosition="before">
            <button mat-menu-item>Candidats</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>Clients</button>
        </mat-menu>
    </mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. We just need to override css for `mat-menu-submenu-icon` class

There is a demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m1zkmv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts